# Why does my auth cookie not save on safari? React frontend/Express backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

For reference, I am using two different domains for frontend/backend. Note: it works when using localhost & local settings, on safari.

When I send the request, the status is 200 but the cookie just isn't saved. It works just fine on chrome. Content blockers are also disabled for the page. Code below.

Frontend in React (Vercel)

```
fetch(`${address}/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: username.current.value,
                password: password.current.value
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            withCredentials: true
        })
```

Backend in Express (Render.com)

```
// index.js
app.use(cors(allowedOrigins));
const mainRoutes = require('./routes/main');
app.use('/', mainRoutes); // main routes

// main.js

router.post('/login', accountController.login); // login

// accountController.js

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "https://st-events.vercel.app");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

        // sends cookie to the user
        res.cookie('authentication', cookieValue, { 
            maxAge: 604800000,
            httpOnly: true, 
            secure: true,
            domain: 'event-manager-backend-d7uu.onrender.com',
            path: '/',
            sameSite: 'none'
        }).send();
```

I tried editing the cookie & cors settings but nothing seems to fix it on safari. If you want to check the full code, the githubs are below:
https://github.com/charleywolf/event-manager-frontend
https://github.com/charleywolf/event-manager-backend

**EDIT**
The sign-in/cookies now save when disabling cross-site tracking on all websites in safari. Obviously, that's less than ideal because many users won't do that just to access a site. I'm now trying to find a way for safari not to flag my cookies as cross-site tracking.